# python decorator if sentence

Tags: python, decorator

python decorator if sentence

```
def extrafun(hi):
    if hi>10:
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(x):
                print('before decora`enter code here`oting')
                func(x)`enter code here`
                print('After decoraoting')
            return wrapper
        return decorator

@extrafun(12)
def newfunc(c):
    print("this is new function")

# @extrafun(9)
# def newfunc(c):
#     print("뭐야?")
# error
```

```
def extrafun(hi):
    if hi>10:
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(x):
                print('before decoraoting')
                func(x)
                print('After decoraoting')
            return wrapper
        return decorator
    else:`enter code here`
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(x):
                print('구분어떻게해?')
                func(x)
                print('구분어떻게해?')
            return wrapper
        return decorator
```

```
@extrafun(12)
def newfunc(c):
    print("this is new function")

@extrafun(9)
def newfunc(c):
    print("뭐야?")

newfunc(12)
```

구분어떻게해?
뭐야?
구분어떻게해?

```
In [14]:

newfunc(9)
```

구분어떻게해?
뭐야?`enter code here
구분어떻게해?

Comment: StackOverflow is an English website. Could you please ask your question in english?

Answer (score 0):

```
def extrafun(hi):
    if hi>10:
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(x):
                print('before decoraoting')
                func(x)
                print('After decoraoting')
            return wrapper
        return decorator
    else:
        def decorator(func):
            def wrapper(x):
                print('구분어떻게해?')
                func(x)
                print('구분어떻게해?')
            return wrapper
        return decorator
@extrafun(12)
def newfunc(c):
    print("this is new function")

@extrafun(9)
def newfunc2(c):
    print("나는 바보다")
```

```
newfunc(12)
```

before decoraoting
this is new function
After decoraoting

```
newfunc2(9)
```

구분어떻게해?
나는 바보다
구분어떻게해?